# How to predict the type of intrinsic defect?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, materials, solid-state-chemistry

Intrinsic defects occur when a pure material crystal shows either vacancy or interstitialcy. When an ionic compound has vacancy, the imbalance in charge has to be compensated with another defect. When a vacancy is balanced with another vacancy it is called Schottky defect , when it is compensated by an interstitial defect, it is called Frenkel defect. When species are exchanged on the sites, the defect is called anti-site defect.

Knowing all of that, how do we predict the type of intrinsic defects in a given material such as $\ce{HgSe}$ or $\ce{Ba3N2}$ ?

Comment: first google landed me here,is it u? http://lfhck.com/questions/how-to-predict-the-type-of-intrinsic-defect

Comment: I posted this question 2 years ago, that lfhck is a mirror of the original post. I am not sure whether direct googling would help. One needs to really know inorganic chemistry.

Comment: seemingly why i kind of gave up, all i know is organic, sorry

Comment: In general, there are not good heuristics to predict what defects in a crystal will have the lowest formation energies, much less diffusion energies. Even in the alkali halides there are anomalies in which defects predominate.

Comment: Don't know about anti site defects but frenkel defects occur when there is significant covalency (like in Mercury selenide) but you get schottky defects with more ionic materials (like barium nitride)

Comment: @RobChem, interesting! Could you explain a bit why is that the case? Why do we get vacancy balancing defects when there is ionic material? Why do we get interstitials when we have covalency? If you put it in answer format it would be even better.